# Representation of a triangulation by different data structures

Tags: python, graphics, scipy, triangulation, delaunay

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

points = np.array([[0.2, 0], [0.1, 1.1], [0.6, 0.1], [1, 0.5], [0.6,0.9], [0.4,0.4]])
tri = Delaunay(points)

#plot
plt.triplot(points[:,0], points[:,1], tri.simplices)
plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], 'o')
plt.show()

print(tri.points)
"""
[[0.2 0. ]
[0.  1.1]
[0.6 0. ]
[1.  1. ]
[0.2 0.8]
[0.4 0.4]]
"""
print(tri.simplices)
"""
[[0 5 1]
[5 4 1]
[4 5 3]
[5 2 3]
[2 5 0]]
"""
```

[image: Delaunay]

This is a delaunay triangulation of points array. I have points (tri.points) and triangles (tri.simplices) arrays as outputs. I need to convert these into **half-edge data structure, winged-edge data structure, corner table data structure and quad edge data structures** for different representations and choose which one stores less space. Are there any libraries for these conversions in Python or should I code it all by myself?

Comment: Sorry for my five cents, but if you think about memory optimization. Perhaps this library https://github.com/nschloe/meshio brings more ideas.

Comment: Can you provide formal answer? So that I can accept it. @ivan-usalko

Answer (score 0):

[ipgraph](https://igraph.org/python/#docs) and [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html) spring to mind.

You might also want to look at the [PythonGraphApi's](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonGraphApi) section *General thoughts* as this lists quite a number of libraries...

To be honest, I have extremely limited experience with graph libraries myself, so your mileage may vary...